# Python in Visual Studio 2017 fails to find modules via the Search Paths

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, visual-studio-2017

I am trying to add an existing python project with a python virtual environment to visual studio 2017 so I can debug it.

The project also has some external dependencies,

Everything is arranged in the following folders

`C:\myproject\code`

`C:\myproject\portablepython`

`C:\myproject\pylibrary`

I created the project using `File->New Project->Python->From Existing Python Code`

I added PortablePython virtual environment using `Tools->Python->Python Environments` using C:\myproject\portablepython as prefix path,
`C:\myproject\portablepython\python.exe` as Interpreter path
`C:\myproject\portablepython\wpython.exe` as Windowed Interpreter path
Language auto detected as 3.6, 64 bit, and I even added `C:\myproject\pylibrary` as the path environment variable.

I also added pylibrary to project search paths so that it looks like `..\pylibrary`

My issue is when I build the project, it fails on the very first pylibrary import with `ImportError("cannot import name 'mdevice'",)` on the line

`from mdevice import mdevice`

And this module is clearly in the `C:\myproject\pylibrary` path

What's more interesting is when I remove `portablepython` from Python environments, and it defaults to Python 3.6, it finds the first module, but it can't find the second module on the line below the first one.

Both modules are in `C:\myproject\pylibrary`

I don't know what is wrong with Visual Studio here, seems like a bug to me

Side note: I had to create the virtual environment using `Tools->Python->Python Environments` because when I right click on project and select `Add Virtual Environment` and select `C:\myproject\portablepython` it actually shows `"We Cannot Create a Virtual Environment at the Specified path. Choose a folder that does not exist, is empty, or contains and existing virtual environment"` eventhough it clearly contains the correct python files in this folder.

Answer (score 0):

Python paths aren't set specifically by python code or project files, they are set as system path variables.
In order to add the modules and the interpreter, I needed to add a PYTHONPATH to system variables and have it point to the folder containing modules, then add the Python.exe path to the top of the path list