# How can I set up a python environment path for executable and libraries in Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, windows, visual-studio-code

I am not a python programmer, and I got tasked with using existing python code that comes shipped with its own python executable (as I understand its called interpreter) and its own python modules.

I understand this is what defines a python environment, except that there is no env/scripts folder or env.txt file. I just have the version of python and separately in another folder I have the modules.

What I would like to do is create a Visual Studio Code project/workspace that uses that python.exe to run and debug, and has a reference to the folder that has the python modules.

I cannot find this option to configure paths anywhere in Visual Studio code. I tried doing this in Visual Studio 2017, but it refused to use the path I provided to the modules. This is my original question for Visual Studio, it was unanswered so I decided to try Visual Studio code [Python in Visual Studio 2017 fails to find modules via the Seath Paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51601594/python-in-visual-studio-2017-fails-to-find-modules-via-the-seath-paths)

If this is not possible, and I need to set up some scripts or it to use the directory for the modules and a directory for the interpreter, I can do this, but I cannot find any tutorials on setting it up, and documentation is scarce and unreliable.
Is there a tool which can set up the environment, so I don't have to write any scripts by hand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [set `"python.pythonPath"`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/settings-reference#_general-settings) to point to your Python executable.

Answer (score 0):

My solution, explained better for other people who don't use python. Python paths aren't set specifically by python code or project files, they are set as system path variables.

In order to add the modules and the interpreter, I needed to add a PYTHONPATH to system variables and have it point to the folder containing modules, then add the Python.exe path to the top of the path list